# Get recipient number from SMS in Android

Tags: android, sms

This may sound strange but I want to get to which number I've received SMS on, on my phone. I can get the mobile number for the SIM present inside with `telephonyManager.getLine1Number()` (although it is not guaranteed that I'll get the phone number). But what in case I have two SIMs present in my phone. As `telephonyManager.getLine1Number()` will only return me SIM info for first/active SIM only.

**Edited** : I also tried to get all the info that I get whenever I receive any SMS, but I could not find anything interesting.

So is there any way to get recipient's number (and not sender's number) from the SMS received?

Answer (score -2):

Try this code,

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
```

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

`Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
if (extras == null)
    return;

Object[] pdus = (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");

String[] fromAddress = new String[pdus.length];
SmsMessage[] message = new SmsMessage[pdus.length]; 

for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {

     message[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
    fromAddress[i] = message[i].getOriginatingAddress();   // it will give the address from where SMS was originated.                  


}`

}